# Accessing data in Entity Framework relationship tables

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to access the data in the relationship table created by 
Entity Framework: I have two tables (posting the corresponding models here)

I have models for `Event` and `Child`, but not for `ChildEvent`.

Each `Event` has multiple children and each `Child` has multiple events as it is a many-to-many relationship. Now I am able to add and delete the entries into the tables. But when I am trying to access the children associated with each event, I am getting a null.

I have tried googling and I found some posts on easy loading. I have tried turning that off but the problem persists still. Is there any way I can get the children associated with each event. I do not have a model for `ChildEvent`? I cannot directly query the `ChildEvent` table.

```
Public Class Event {       // This is the event model
   public int EventId      // This is the primary key
   public int EventName

   public virtual ICollection<Child> Children // used to reference Child table
}

Public Class Child {       // This is the Child Model
   public int ChildId      // primary key
   public string FirstName 
   public virtual ICollection<Event> Events // used to refer to Event table
}
```

I have the relationship table created the by Entity Framework

`ChildEvent`:

```
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
```

Comment: yes it is code first

Comment: Why you don't have access to ChildEvent class?

Comment: The way I can access a table is via Models (MVC architecture). Now, Entity framework creates the CHildEvent Table internally. This Table is present in the Database but there is no corresponding model for ChildEvent. So I cannot access it directly.

Comment: How about creating your own relationships table?

Comment: That is always an option but one of the main purposes of using Entity Framework would be lost. I just want to know a way of accessing the relationship table using this framework functionalities :)

Comment: Do you have any mapping code for your entities?

Comment: Are you using the include option? context.Event.Include(x => x.Children);

Comment: It is working now. I am using Include option. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that Entity Frameowrk knows how you want your Many To Many relationships setup. This way Lazy Loading will work and EF will map Events to Children and Children to Events.

```
 public class EventMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<Event>
        {
             public EventMap()
             {
                 HasMany(e => e.Children)
                  .WithMany(c => c.Events)
                  .Map(m =>
                     {
                      m.MapLeftKey("EventId");  
                      m.MapRightKey("ChildId"); 
                      m.ToTable("Event_Children");
                  });
             }
        }
```

Comment: I have used the mapping before too. I think we need work with the Include option to overcome the lazy loading issue. It is working fine now. Thanks :)